# PyQt5 change widget below the button instead of behind it

Tags: python, pyqt

When I add the plot widget it is placed in the background (behind the button). I want it below the start button.

Here is the picture of what I get. As you can see the plot is behind the start button and the placeholder:
[image]

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):

        MainWindow.resize(1710, 650)
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle('StarBot')

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(pg.PlotWidget())


        self.centralwidget = QWidget()
        self.centralwidget.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QRect(20, 30, 150, 41))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet(
        '''background-color: #202025; 
        border-width: 1px; 
        border-style: solid; 
        border-color:  #202025;''')

        self.pushButton.setText('START')

        self.output = QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.output.setGeometry(QRect(20, 540, 671, 91))
        self.output.setObjectName("output")
        self.output.setStyleSheet(custom_style)
        

        self.historical_data = QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.historical_data.setGeometry(QRect(705, 30, 981, 600))
        self.historical_data.setObjectName("historical_data")
        self.historical_data.setStyleSheet(custom_style)
        self.historical_data.setPlainText(text)

        self.portfolio_value = QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.portfolio_value.setGeometry(QRect(180, 30, 511, 41))
        self.portfolio_value.setObjectName("portfolio_value")

        self.portfolio_value.setStyleSheet(
        '''background-color: #202025; 
        border-width: 1px; 
        border-style: solid; 
        border-color:  #202025;''')


        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        MainWindow.setStyleSheet(
        '''background-color: #252526; 
        border-width: 1px; 
        border-style: solid;''')

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How can I change the location of the frame so that it is placed below the start button?

Comment: 1. You're only adding the plot widget to the layout, not the others; 2. Don't edit pyuic generated files, but follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) instead.

Comment: @musicamante thanks for the reply, wait.. did i miss something? Actualy i nver touch the code, i just add the pygraph.. before this the pygraph has it own window..  i tried the .setlayout() the pygraph now join the main window but i cant configure the geometry

Comment: If you added the pyqtgraph widget to the code, you "touched" it. You have to add *all* widgets to the layout (which should be set in Designer).

Comment: I see, so not just  one .additem(pg.Plotwidget()),  will try it out

Comment: `addItem()` is only used privately from QLayouts, so it should be `addWidget()`, but the problem is that you are working with a Designer file, so you should add a layout *there*. Right click on an empty area of the window and select the grid layout from the "Lay out" submenu. Then rebuild the py file with pyuic and **do not edit it**, then create a new script for your *main* program, follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) and add the plot widget to the existing layout.

Answer (score 0):

i added this before adding widgets
self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame